# How do you use callback collections generated by FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, callback, factory-bot

I'm writing tests for my code using Rspec and FactoryGirl - where a User has_one Organization and an Organization has_many users. Organization name is set to unique, and I was testing the users happily using the association: organization (within my User factory) feature of FactoryGirl (with a bunch of hacked together traits for wrong_user tests. It got to the stage where this wasn't adequate (I need a collection of users within an Organization for some of the tests, and the above setup doesn't work properly) so I'm now trying to build collections of users inside my Organization Factories instead. This is working for some of the tests but not others, and I think I'm not using the created user(s) correctly in my tests.

Factory Code:

```
factory :organization do
    organization_name       "New Example Org"
    before(:create) do |organization|
        organization.users << FactoryGirl.build(:user)
        organization.users << FactoryGirl.build(:user, email: "email2@example.com")
    end
    trait :wrong do
        organization_name   "Wrong Org"
        before(:create) do |organization|
        organization.users << FactoryGirl.build(:user, email: "email3@example.com")
    end
    end
end
```

Failing test code:

```
describe "as wrong user" do
    let(:organization) { FactoryGirl.create(:organization, :wrong)}
  let(:user) {organization.users.first}
    let(:wrong_user) { organization.users.last }
    before { sign_in user, no_capybara: true }

describe "submitting a GET request to the Users#show action", type: :request do
        before { get user_path(wrong_user) }
        specify { expect(response.body).not_to match(full_title(user.name)) }
        specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path) }
    end
  describe "submitting a GET request to the Organizations#show action", type: :request do
    before { get organization_path(wrong_user.organization) }
    specify { expect(response.body).not_to match(full_title(wrong_user.organization.organization_name)) }
    specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path) }
  end
end
```

The results;

```
  26) Authentication authorization as wrong user submitting a GET request to the Organizations#show action should redirect to "/"
 Failure/Error: specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path) }
   Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:109:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

  25) Authentication authorization as wrong user submitting a GET request to the Organizations#show action should not match "Title | Wrong Org"
 Failure/Error: specify { expect(response.body).not_to match(full_title(wrong_user.organization.organization_name)) }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this in the end. The issue was that I can only call one factory "Organization", and therefore any subsequent traits or builds I put on that factory are all associated with the same Organization_id. The fix was as follows:

Factory Code:

```
factory :organization do
    trait :name_one do
    organization_name       "New Example Org"
    end

    trait :name_two do
        organization_name   "Any Wrong Org"
    end
    trait :with_users do
    before(:create) do |organization|
        organization.users << FactoryGirl.build(:user)
        organization.users << FactoryGirl.build(:user, name: "Wrong Name", email: "email2@example.com")
    end
end
    trait :wrong do
        before(:create) do |organization|
        organization.users << FactoryGirl.build(:user, name: "another wrong name", email: "email3@example.com")
    end
    end
    end

factory :user do
    name                    "Example Name"
    email                   "email@example.com"
    password                "foobar"
    password_confirmation   "foobar"

    trait :as_admin do
        admin                   true
    end
end
end
```

Test Code:

```
describe "as wrong user" do
    let(:organization) { FactoryGirl.create(:organization, :name_one, :with_users)}
  let(:user) {organization.users.first}
    let(:wrong_org) { FactoryGirl.create(:organization, :name_two, :wrong)}
  let(:wrong_user) {wrong_org.users.last}
    before { sign_in user, no_capybara: true }

    describe "submitting a GET request to the Users#edit action", type: :request do
        before { get edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
        specify { expect(response.body).not_to match(full_title('Edit user')) }
        specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path) }
    end

    describe "submitting a PATCH request to the Users#update action", type: :request do
        before { patch user_path(wrong_user) }
        specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path) }
    end

    describe "submitting a GET request to the Users#show action", type: :request do
        before { get user_path(wrong_user) }
        specify { expect(response.body).not_to match(full_title(user.name)) }
        specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path) }
    end
  describe "submitting a GET request to the Organizations#show action", type: :request do
    before { get organization_path(wrong_user.organization) }
    specify { expect(response.body).not_to match(full_title(wrong_user.organization.organization_name)) }
    specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path) }
  end
end
describe "as non-admin user" do
  let(:organization) { FactoryGirl.create(:organization, :name_one, :with_users)}
  let(:non_admin) {organization.users.first}
  let(:user) {organization.users.last}

  before { sign_in non_admin, no_capybara: true }
  describe "submitting a DELETE request to the Users#destroy action", type: :request do
    before { delete user_path(user) }
    specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path) }
      end
   end
    end
```

All the tests are now green - so by placing the Organization Name into specific traits (rather than as a general part of the Factory) I'm able to create two different organizations and add users to each. Hope it helps someone else.